# JQuery: фильтрация таблицы по диапазону лет

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте. Есть простая HTML-таблица. Нужно организовать фильтрацию по разным полям, в т.ч. по годам. По полям фильтрацию я сделал просто, а вот как по диапазону лет (напр. от 1900 до 1950) сделать - немного непонятно. Базовый код выглядит так (очевидно надо добавить ещё поля ввода начального и конечного года).

Селектор contains выглядит ужасно неповоротливо в данной ситуации. Есть ли несложный способ прикрутить подобный поиск?

```
<input type="text" id="filter-input"  value=""/><br/>
<table class="table-class">
<tr>
    <th>Название книги</th><th>Автор</th><th>Дата публикации</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Пример 1</td><td>Василий</td><td>1951</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Пример 2</td><td>Иван</td><td>1990</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
   <td>Пример 3</td><td>Пётр</td><td>1955</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var filter = $("#filter-input");
filter.keyup(function(e) {
    var author = $(this).val();
    $('.table-class tr:not(:first)').filter(function() {
        if (!$(this).find('td:eq(1)').is(':contains("' + author + '")')) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $(this).show();
            return false;
        }
    }).hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Лучше назначить классы `td.field-name` и искать по ним (примерно так http://jsfiddle.net/p2R6F/ ), так же в сети полно [готовых решений](https://www.google.ru/search?q=javascript+table+filtering&oq=javascript+table+filtering) для поиска по таблице.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно! Просто я полный нуб в jQuery. 
Буду дальше разбираться.